# Regexp for finding second space within 20 characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a Java regexp that matches a string in this format:

```
AXXXXYYYYB
```

Where *XXXX* is a string that terminates at the 20th character or the **second** space, whichever comes first, and *YYYY* is a string that terminates at the 20th character or the **first** space, whichever comes first.

And I need *XXXX* and *YYYY* to be the first and second capture groups.

I can get it to work terminating at the **first** space in *XXXX* with this:

```
^A([^ ]{1,20}) ?([^ ]{1,20})B$
```

But I can't figure out the rule that would terminate at the 20th character or the **second** space.

Also, I don't care if either capture group ends up with an extra leading or trailing space.

Sample input -> output:

```
MR SMITH BROOKLYN -> "MR SMITH" and "BROOKLYN" (separated at second space)
MR SMYTHE-JONES BRONX -> "MR SMYTHE-JONES" and "BRONX" (separated at second space)
12345678901234567890QUEENS -> "12345678901234567890" and "QUEENS" (separated at 20th character)
1234567890 1234567890QUEENS -> "1234567890 123456789" and "0QUEENS" (separated at 20th character)
1234567890 1234567890STATEN ISLAND -> "1234567890 123456789" and "0STATEN" (separated at 20th character, then separated at space)
```

Comment: could you provide some examples with expected output?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it as soon as I hit save and fixed it just as you posted the request for clarification. Sorry!

Comment: What happens to string that hass only 1 space and characters less than 20 ?

Comment: First string ends at second space or 20th character, whichever comes first. From that point, the second string ends at the 20th character or first space. If there aren't enough characters, then nothing will match. "A B" will match as "A B" and "".

Answer (score 1):

```
^([^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)[ ](.*)$|(.{20})(.*)$
```

You can try this.Grab the captures.

1)`([^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)[ ](.*)` will break on second space

2)`(.{20})(.*)` will break on 20 characters.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/gT6kI4/4

Comment: If the first string is >20 characters but there are two spaces in the total string, this will return the first string >20 characters. MR SUPERDUPERLONGNAMESMITH BROOKLYN will return the first string too long. You missed the "whichever comes first" part.

Comment: Closer, but `MR SMITHERLY BROOKLYN` breaks as `MR SMITHERLY BROOKLY` and `N` instead of as `MR SMITHERLY` and `BROOKLYN`.

Comment: @vks : look at this (http://regex101.com/r/gT6kI4/8) it is suppose to split at the `x's`, we need a variable length look-behind.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, which makes use of lookbehind:

```
"([^ ]*(?:[ ][^ ]*)?)(?<!.{21})[ ]?([^ ]{0,20})"
```

`([^ ]*(?:[ ][^ ]*)?)(?<!.{21})` matches and captures the first part, which must be strictly less than 21 characters **and** contains maximum one space. Due to the greedy quantifiers, it will always try for the longest possible string first (always match past the first space first) and reduces its length when limited by the look-behind. The lookbehind only allows the matcher to proceed when you can't find 21 characters to match, which means the part in front is less than 20 characters.

Since the first part can end with space, I need to match it with `[ ]?`.

Then, since the second part can't contain any space (since it breaks at the first space), it can simply be matched and captured by `([^ ]{0,20})`.

Note that this solution assumes there is no *line separator* character in the input string.

There is a caveat: the first part may contain trailing space, if it is the first space and it is the 20th character. You can prevent that by making a small change:

```
"([^ ]*(?:[ ][^ ]+)?)(?<!.{21})[ ]?([^ ]{0,20})"
                 ^
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/wvGq4w)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this could be done using one regex pattern.
I suggest running this pattern first:
`^(.{20})(.*)$`
if sub-pattern no. 1 contains more than one space then fail it and run this pattern instead
`^(\S+\s\S+)\s(.*)$`

Comment: If the first string is >20 characters but there are two spaces in the total string, this will return the first string >20 characters. MR SUPERDUPERLONGNAMESMITH BROOKLYN will return the first string too long. You missed the "whichever comes first" part.